# Pulling a custom H1 field into page code

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I wanted to create a custom field for pages where i can populate a custom H1 tag into the page. I used **Advanced Custom Fields** to make the field labeled ***"custom-h1"*** and then added the script call to header.php to pull through to all pages, but it's not currently working for all page types.

I've got one bit of script that works for all normal pages, and one that works for all category pages.. but I need a piece of script that will work across the whole site (all page types). Code below:

**If I use this, then it succesfully pulls field data through, but only for normal "pages" (eg /contact/):**

```
<!-- Custom H1 Field -->
<h1><?php the_field('custom-h1'); ?></h1>
<!-- End Custom H1 Field -->
```

**If I use this, I get the opposite affect (it ONLY works for category pages):**

```
<!-- Custom H1 Field -->
<h1><?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  
the_field('custom-h1', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); 
?></h1>
<!-- End Custom H1 Field -->
```

Please help! I feel like this is a really basic solution, I simply don't know enough about PHP to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<?php echo "<h1>";
 $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; echo "</h1>"  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although there's nothing here to call the field contents..? There needs to be: "the_field('custom-h1'....

Comment: You mean you want to fetch a query wrap by H1 element?.

Comment: Yes exactly :) So if I went to the front end of the page, and viewed source, I'd see the field contents wrapped in an h1 tag

Comment: actually, you should fetch your query first before you wrap it with an element. <?php foreach(){ ?> <h1><?php //print ur query ?> </h1> <?php } ?>